# Limit of equation as $m \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, limits, probability-limit-theorems

I was taking a look at this question: [Convergence in distribution to a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113354/convergence-in-distribution-to-a-limit-with-distribution-function-fx-1-exp)

And I’m struggling with working out the limit given at the end of the solution.

Overall I can get half of the way there, but the bit I’m missing is how as $m \rightarrow \infty$ then
$$e^{-mw} \left( 1 - \frac{w}{m} \right)^{-m^{2}} \rightarrow e^{w^{2}/2}$$

Any explanation of calculating the limit would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at the logarithm of both sides. Note that $\log(1-\epsilon)\sim-\epsilon$... oops, come to think of it you need the next term in the asymptotics, sorry

Comment: Remember $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac an)^n = e^a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-mw-m^{2} \ln (1-\frac w m)= -mw -m^{2}(-\frac w m +\frac {w^{2}} {2m^{2}}+o(m^{-2}))$$ $$=-\frac {w^{2}} 2 +o(1) \to -\frac {w^{2}} 2$$ so the limit is $e^{-w^{2}/2}$